# URL rewriting with subdomain structure in php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create a URL like category.\ArticleName

This is what I have written in my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).msite.com/([a-zA-Z]+) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) $1/Html/HomePage.php?Category=%1&name=%2 [NC,QSA]
```

I actaully tried

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).msite.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule (.*) $1/Html/HomePage.php?Category=%1 [NC,QSA]
```

It worked fine means wild-card subdomain etc are enabled.

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? please give an example!

Comment: I want to make SEO friendly URL with subdomain. categoryName.mysite.com/productName should map to mysite.com/html/homepage.php?category=categoryName&name=productName

Answer (score 0):

Close, try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).msite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /Html/HomePage.php?Category=%1&name=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

You'll need the two extra conditions in the beginning so that valid requests don't get routed to HomePage.php.